# How to copy the code used in one sheet/tab in a workbook to create a report in another sheet/tab within the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say, there is a report that has already been created in a sheet in a work book using macros. I want to create another report within the same workbook in another sheet(tab) with the exact same code in VBA which was used to create the report that has already been created. How do i copy and make those codes work in a different sheet to create a similar report?

Answer (score 0):

Any code in the Worksheet itself should use `Me` to refer to itself - this way, it will work when copied/duplicated

Any other code should take the Worksheet to act on as a Argument, or as Module Level Object:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateReport(TargetSheet As Worksheet)
    TargetSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "Hello"
End Sub
```

or

```
Option Explicit
Public TargetSheet AS Worksheet

Sub CreateReport()
    If TargetSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'In case the object has not been set
    TargetSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "Hello"
End Sub
```

Then you can duplicate a "master" template sheet, and run the macros to target it

Comment: Could you elaborate? e.g. The report already created is for cargo moving internationally from the US. So there is a button with a macros assigned for London, another for Germany etc. Now I want to create another report with the exact same layout/format, for cargo moving domestically within the US. So essentially, the buttons will change to New York, etc. how do I go about editing the first report to suit my needs to create the new report? Can I just copy the macros used from the first report? Or will I have to add/edit something else to make the macros for the new report work?

Comment: You can copy the macros as a starting point, but you will need to change any Sheet References (e.g. `Sheet("London")`) to point at whatever the new sheets are called